# Text align wrapping with longer string

Tags: css

I have this css code:

```
<div class='divfooterbox'>
  <div style='float:left'>Text Left</div>
  <div style='float:right'>Text Right</div>             
</div>

.divfooterbox {
  position: absolute;
  height: 40px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 2px;
  right: 2px;
}
.divfooterbox div {
   height: 100%;
   color: white;
   line-height: 40px;
   padding-left: 8px;
   padding-right: 8px;
}
```

- Text right is a text fixed size.
- Text left is a variable length size.

If text left is a longer then 25/30 char I have problems, the left text wraps.

Comment: You have fixed height parent and you wants text wrapping as well?

Comment: I would like you so

Comment: Your question is not very clear but may be this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Muhammad_Usman/8uLc47cf/) will help you.